# Why create an object with a static shared_ptr returning member?

Tags: c++, constructor, static

I've seen such pattern around and am curious what's the benefit of such pattern. What's the difference between creating an object with static and with pure constructor?

```
class Foo {
static std::shared_ptr<Foo> create(); // why expose this function?

Foo(folly::observer::Observe<Config> config);
};
```

Comment: This is called a "factory" and it ensures that you have control of all circumstances where the object is created

Answer (score 1):

One reason to do this would be to force all instances of the object to be owned by shared_ptr's (instead of statically constructed). This is especially helpful when using shared_from_this().

For example, consider the following program:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo;

void globalFunc(const std::shared_ptr<Foo> &) {
    // do something with the ptr
}

class Foo
    : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
public:
    Foo() {}
    void classMemberFunc()
    {
        globalFunc(shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

In this program, a Foo object can access/pass a shared pointer to *itself*, similar to how it can access/pass the this pointer. When classMemberFunc() is called on an object of Foo, globalFunc receives a reference to a shared_ptr the holds Foo.

However, with this design, Foo needs to be owned by a shared_ptr in the first place.

```
int main()
{
    // valid use
    auto sptr = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    sptr->classMemberFunc();
}
```

If a Foo object isn't owned by a shared_ptr, shared_from_this() has undefined behavior before C++17 and a runtime error in C++17.

```
int main()
{
    // invalid use - undefined behavior or runtime error
    Foo nonPtrFoo;
    nonPtrFoo.classMemberFunc();
}
```

We would like to prevent this at compile time. We can do this using the static "create" method and a private constructor.

```
class Foo
    : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<Foo> create() // force shared_ptr use
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo);
    }
    void classMemberFunc()
    {
        globalFunc(shared_from_this());
    }
private:
    Foo() {} // prevent direct construction
};

int main()
{
    // valid use
    auto sptr = Foo::create();
    sptr->classMemberFunc();

    // invalid use - now compile error
    Foo nonPtrFoo;
    nonPtrFoo.classMemberFunc();
}
```